# Validate if new value of <h:inputText> is not higher than old value

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf

I want to control the value in an `<h:inputText>` ..I want that once I leave the input fieldsif I have a higher value than the old value an error message is displayed and I can not validate fields after entering a value lower (the older value is loaded from the database)

I have done somthing like this :

```
  <p:column headerText="Qte" >
        <h:inputText  value="#{ligne.qte}"   styleClass="span12"   required="true" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.changeQte}" >
        <h:message id="message"></h:message>
         <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{myBean.onQteChange}" update="message" />
         </h:inputText>
        </p:column>
```

in myBean I have this two methods :

```
public void onQteChange(){
    String message =null;
    int newqte = getQte();
    if (newqte > previousQTE  ){
        message="invalid qte";
    }
}

public void onQteChange(){
    String message =null;
    int newqte = getQte();
    if (newqte > previousQTE  ){
        message="invalid qte";
    }
}
```

Can someone tells me how can I do this because even if I try to make ajax call into my inputtext I have no result ?

Comment: Use a normal `Validator`.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC can you tell me please haw can I put a condition if I use a normal `validator` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 public void onQteChange(){
   String message =null;
   int newqte = getQte();
   if (newqte > previousQTE  ){
   message="invalid qte";
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
    "message",new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message,message));
  }
}


<p:column headerText="Qte" >
        <h:inputText  value="#{ligne.qte}"  id="x" styleClass="span12"   required="true" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.changeQte}" >
         <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{myBean.onQteChange}" update="message" />
         </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="message" for="x" />
 </p:column>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer @S19 I try it but unfortunatly still have nothing as result

Comment: Add an id to inputText, and add for argument in the message :
<p:inputText id="x" /> <p:message for="x" />

Comment: If I have an empty `<p:inputText>` I get this error message `j_idt5:article:0:message : erreur de validation. Vous devez indiquer une valeur.` but if I insert a value higher than the old one I still have no control

Comment: Try using onchange instead of onkeyup